# How can I take the second row from the end from the table of the Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to get the second and third rows from the end of the model table.
I know how to get the last row.
But I need - (last - 1) and (last - 2) rows alternately.

How can you get them?

```
qs_select = Model.objects.all()

last_row = qs_select.last()
```

Answer (score 0):

Django querysets not support indexing
You have to convert the queryset into a list yourself and then use the index

```
qs_select = Model.objects.all()

last2_row = list(qs_select)[-2]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Django QuerySets are almost similar to Python lists so some list hence use something like this to access the second last record:-

```py
qs_select = Model.objects.all()
second_last_row = qs_select[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately django doesn't support negative indexing on querysets, so this will not work:

```py
Model.objects.all()[-3:-1] # Will raise negative indexing error
```

Another approach is to cast the whole queryset to a list, and do negative indexing, but this will load your whole table to memory:

```py
list(Model.objects.all())[-3:-1] # Loads your whole table to memory :/
```

So one way to solve this is to sort your table first, for example by the primary key in descending order, and get the 2nd and 3rd row like this:

```py
Model.objects.order_by("-pk")[1:3]
```

This will get the 2nd and 3rd row from the end of your table based on the primary key order.

So if you want the last 3 rows in total:

```py
Model.objects.order_by("-pk")[:3]
```